# Android - Displaying a UDP video stream - handling corrupt packets

Tags: java, android, udp, video-streaming, libvlc

I am trying to achieve a playback of a `UDP` stream that streams packets of `MPEG Transport Stream.`

Right now I was able to continuously read packets and append them to a `.ts file`.
I decided to split the data into separate `.ts files` - each file has a a maximum duration of 3 seconds.
Every time I finish writing to a file - I update the UI to read the most recent file and play it.

I am using the `LibVLC` library to play the `.ts files.`

Right now I am able to play the corresponding videos - but apart from the 3 second delay - There are a lot of dropped frames which cause a very negative user experience.

I believe that that it may be caused due to corrupt packets.

I'd love to hear any insights.

I am using `Android 12`,
`LibVLC` version: org.videolan.android:libvlc-all:3.3.0-eap10
And `UDP` packets as well as `FileOutputStream` to write the packets.

Comment: share some logs, we're as blind as you here